# Окно которое должно открываться в окне

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, gui, qt-designer

У меня есть **`2`** файла - **unt1main.py** главное окно и **unt2window.py**, окно которое должно открываться в окне **unt1main.py**.

То есть я хочу сделать чтобы при нажатии на серую кнопку в **unt1main.py** в этом же окне должно открываться окно **unt2window.py**.

Не должно создаваться 2 окна, второе окно должно открываться в первом окне. Подскажите пожалуйста, как это сделать.

**unt1main.py**:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sys

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1140, 460)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(200, 129))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 16777215))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.centralwidget.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.centralwidget.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setText("")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.pushButton.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(30, 30))
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("border-radius: 15px;\n"
"background-color: rgb(70, 70, 70);")
        self.pushButton.setText("")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(25)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_2, 0, 0, 1, 2)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Окно в окне"))

class ExampleApp1(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.setupUi(self)


if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ExampleApp1()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

unt2window.py:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sys

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1140, 460)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(200, 129))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 16777215))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.centralwidget.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.centralwidget.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setText("")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(25)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_2, 0, 0, 1, 2)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Окно которое должно открываться после нажатия на кнопку"))

class ExampleApp2(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.setupUi(self)


if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ExampleApp2()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: в любом случае оно откроется поверх первого, так зачем усложнять?

Comment: @finally хочу сделать в своем приложении окно настроек, но открывающееся новое окно выглядит не очень

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создайте экземпляр `self.exampleApp2 = ExampleApp2()` и поместите его в `gridLayout`

```
...
    self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.onClicked)

def  onClicked(self):
    self.exampleApp2 = ExampleApp2()
    self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.exampleApp2, 1, 0, 1, 2)

...
```

---

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1140, 460)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(200, 129))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 16777215))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.centralwidget.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.centralwidget.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel("label---", self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setText("label---")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label, 2, 1, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton("pushButton---", self.centralwidget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)

#        self.pushButton.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(30, 30))               # -
        self.pushButton.setFixedSize(QtCore.QSize(30, 30))                  # +++

        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("border-radius: 15px;\n"
"background-color: rgb(70, 70, 70);")
        self.pushButton.setText("")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 3, 0, 2, 2)              # -+
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(25)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_2, 0, 0, 1, 2)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Окно в окне"))


class Ui_MainWindow_2(object):                                          # Ui_MainWindow_2
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1140, 460)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(200, 129))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 16777215))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.centralwidget.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.centralwidget.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setText("")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(25)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_2, 0, 0, 1, 2)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Окно которое должно открываться после нажатия на кнопку"))

class ExampleApp2(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow_2):               # Ui_MainWindow_2
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)


class ExampleApp1(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.onClicked)

    def  onClicked(self):
        self.exampleApp2 = ExampleApp2()
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.exampleApp2, 1, 0, 1, 2)


if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ExampleApp1()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а как закрыть обратно это окно?

Comment: уже решил проблему, добавив одну кнопку на которую забиндил закрытие

Comment: @imapw_ вы путаете понятия `окно`  и `показ виджета в окне`. Если я вас правильно понял вы хотели `...должно открываться в первом окне`, то я вам показал как это делается. Другого вы не спрашивали. Если вам надо `скрыть виджет`, который находится в макете, то это уже другой вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Код ниже по прежнему создает новое окно, однако родительское скрывается.

Измените класс `ExampleApp1` в unt1main.py:

```
class ExampleApp1(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.new_window)

    def new_window(self):
        self.window1 = unt2window.ExampleApp2(window)
        window.hide()
        self.window1.show()
```

И класс `ExampleApp2` в unt2window.py:

```
class ExampleApp2(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent_w=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.parent_w = parent_w
        self.setupUi(self)

    def closeEvent(self, *a, **kw):
        self.parent_w.show()
```